# Idiomatic way to ensure many values are equal

Tags: java

Say I have a list of many primitive variables:

```
final int a = 3;
final int b = 4;
final int c = 4;
final int d = 4;
final int e = 4;
```

What's an idiomatic way to make sure they all hold the same value? The obvious way is simply

```
if (a == b && a == c && a == d && a == e) // ...
```

But I think this is error prone and hard to read, especially when the variables have proper names, unlike my example.

```
if (  numCategories == numTypes && numCategories == numColours
   && numCategories == numStyles && numCategories == numPrices) // ...
```

It would be nice if we could do the comparison like this:

```
if (a == b == c == d == e)
```

but obviously `a == b` resolves to a boolean so we can't compare that to `c`.

Is there a library function in the JDK or another utility library with maybe a signature somewhat like this?

```
static boolean areEqual(int... numbers)
```

then we could use it like so:

```
if (areEqual(a, b, c, d, e)) //...
```

I could easily write a function like this myself, but why reinvent the wheel if you don't have to?

Maybe there's another idiomatic way to accomplish this that I'm missing.

Comment: I would say there's no idiom because needing to do it at all is a bit of a code smell: more than three variables you might expect to be equal, belong in an array or collection.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I saw a condition in our codebase which checked that a number of lists were equal in size and I'm sure it must be an instance of [parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). Still, it got me thinking what a nice way to make that comparison would be if it *were* necessary.

Comment: checking with XOR would be nice :)

Comment: @matoni: Clarity would suffer, to put it mildly. :-) Not least because an XOR check has to be written differently for an even number of variables than an odd number of variables...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was just joking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Stream`s, you can take advantage of some convenient methods to achieve your goal.

You can use `Stream`'s or `IntStream`'s `distinct()` combined with `count()` to find the number of unique elements:

For `int` variables:

```
if (IntStream.of(a,b,c,d,e).distinct().count() == 1) {

}
```

For reference type variables:

```
if (Stream.of(a,b,c,d,e).distinct().count() == 1) {

}
```

Another way, which is probably less efficient (but I'll keep it here since it's the first thing I thought about) is creating a `Stream` of all the elements you want to compare and then collecting them into a `Set` and checking the size of the `Set` is 1 (since `Set` doesn't allow duplicates) :

```
if (IntStream.of(a,b,c,d,e).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == 1) {

}
```

or

```
if (Stream.of(a,b,c,d,e).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == 1) {

}
```

for general `Object`s.

Comment: You can also do `IntStream.of(a,b,c,d,e).distinct().count == 1`.

Comment: The `distinct()` one is very nice. :)

Comment: @Michael You can do it with `IntStream`, to avoid autoboxing.

Comment: @saka1029 Yes, I just realized that and added to the answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: These are all ways of doing it with one-liners, but I can't see any of them being generally-considered idiomatic, at least not yet. I could see the `distinct` version maybe getting there in a few years...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "idiomatic" is a very subjective term. I just went for the simplest expressions I could think of to achieve the stated goal.

Comment: I would say the `distinct` one is so much better than the `Set` one that the `Set` part should be removed from the answer.

Comment: @slim Perhaps I'll change the order. I just posted them in the order they occurred to me :)

Comment: @Eran just drop the Set part entirely. There is absolutely no reason anyone would use it, given the cleaner, more efficient `distinct()`.

Comment: How about `IntStream.of(b, c, d, e).allMatch(x -> x == a)`?  It may be faster than `distinct()`.

Comment: @saka1029 It should fail faster than distinct, so it may be faster when `false` is returned. However, `distinct()` looks cleaner to me.

Comment: @saka1029: Seems like micro-optimization at the cost of clarity. Of course, what this really calls for is `allEqual` on streams. :-) Then it would be `IntStream.of(a, b, c, d, e).allEqual()`

Comment: It would be pretty simple to write a `Collector<Integer,Integer,Boolean>` for `stream.collect(allEqual())`

Answer (score 3):

A naive option is to build methods that receives all the variables as varargs and compare them one after other. If one of them is different you will get `false`

```
public static boolean areEqual(int...nums)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nums.length - 1 ; ++i) {
        if (nums[i] != nums[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Uses

```
if (areEqual(a, b, c, d, e))
```

Comment: I did sort of say this ;) but +1 for the implementation anyway

Comment: @Michael Missed that :)

Comment: It should be until `nums.length - 2` unless you want an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ;)

Comment: @Pelocho No, it shouldn't. `nums.length - 2` will cause you to miss the last number.

Comment: Nope, you won't. Inside the loop you're using `nums[i + 1]` so last item is checked. Beware that `nums[nums.length]` raises an exception

Comment: @Pelocho The condition is `i < nums.length - 1`. Lets assume `length` is 10. What will happen when `i == 8`? `if (nums[8] != nums[9])`. And when `i == 9`? the loop condition will be `false` so nothing will happen. Now the condition is `i < nums.length - 2` what will happen now?

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach. There's no auto-boxing and no magic numbers.

[As per the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), it's also short-circuiting so therefore potentially more efficient than other methods. More importantly, it's very easy to read.

```
IntStream.of(a, b, c, d).allMatch(x -> x == e);
```

<sub>Credit to [saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279/saka1029).</sub>